# scrape a tag with multiple attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a tag that has 3 attributes. I have used this code but I get none as a result. I know that this tag exist in the html source.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.immobiliare.it/69866648-Vendita-Quadrilocale-via-Mario-Ridolfi-32-Roma.html')  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
result=soup.find('div', attrs={ 'class':'col-xs-12 description-text text expanded', 'aria-expanded':'true', 'role':'contentinfo'})
```

I am getting it wrong somewhere in the syntax?

Comment: Can you provide an URL or the relevant HTML please? Also, more of your code.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: the desired output is the text inside the tag which is the description of a particular house.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are right, but you have run JavaScript in advance. Remember if you desire to crawl something so you should disable JavaScript. Because it can rewrite you tag's class, data, etc.

```
result = soup.find('div',
             attrs={ 'class':'col-xs-12 description-text text-compressed',
                     'aria-expanded':"false",
                      'role':'contentinfo'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# create a function to look for attrs and attr values
def foo(tag):
  return tag.has_attr('aria-expanded') and tag.has_attr('role') and tag['aria-expanded']=='true' and tag['role']=='contentinfo'

# first do a css select on classes
divs = soup.select('div.col-xs-12.description-text.text.expanded')

# then take out any that don't have the attrs/vals we need
divs = [ div for div in divs if foo(div)]
```

It's not very elegant but I've never figured out a better way.

Answer (score 1):

missing the `-` in `text expanded` and because you use `.find()` which select first element you can just:

```
result = soup.find('div', attrs={'role':'contentinfo'})
# or
result = soup.select_one('div[role="contentinfo"]')
```